# Why does my embedded EPS look pixelated on my Photoshop PDF?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, vector, pdf, raster, eps

I have a PSD file with an embedded .eps logo. When I export to Photoshop PDF and zoom in, all the text and shapes look very smooth, but the Smart Object .eps ends up not retaining its vector status.

When I double click the .eps smart object in Photoshop, the preview that loads shows me that it clearly is vector (I can zoom very far, and it'll be smooth).

However when I embed this in Photoshop and export to PDF, no dice. I've also tried with .ai and .pdf versions of the logo.

I am using Press Quality on the PDF export settings.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Looks like I found my own answer!

> Smart Objects in Photoshop are always rasterized at the resolution of
>   the Photoshop file. There's no way to stop it (except to place the AI
>   logo directly from Illustrator). Yes, I know, it's sad.   It's type
>   and vector Photoshop shape layers that can be "saved" at full vector
>   resolution by saving as Photoshop PDF format.

Source: https://forums.adobe.com/thread/1279902

Comment: Nice, be sure to mark this the accepted answer please. You'll earn some rep if you care and it will prevent the SE Robot from auto-bumping the question every so often on us.